# VBA Runtime error 1004 for selecting data in column

Tags: vba, excel

Hi i want to select data that are below of the found cell `MEASURED VALUE` but i'm getting runtime error and don't know why.

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Range
Dim j As Range


Set ws = Worksheets("bank")

Set i = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Find(What:="MEASURED VALUE", LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(1, 0)


Set j = Range(i, Range(i).End(xlDown))


End Sub
```

Error occurs in `Set j = Range(i, Range(i).End(xlDown))`

p.s i know it is problably stupid question but im begginer. Thank you.

Comment: Write `MsgBox i & Range(i).End(xlDown)` before the error. What is the message?

Comment: @Vityata No massage but same error.

Comment: Can you try `Set j = Range(i, Range(i.Address).End(xlDown))` instead of the line with the error?

Comment: @Vityata That worked but can you explain why it worked? thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case that `i` is found, if you try this, it works:

`Set j = Range(i, Range(i.Address).End(xlDown))`

The reason it works is because `Range()` expects a string within and `i.Address` gives a string. Another way to make it work is:

`Set j = Range(i, i.End(xlDown))`

Here you do not use `Range()`, but you use the `i`, which is already defined as range, thus it has the `.End(Direction As xlDirection)` property. Whenever you work with `.Find`, it is a good practice to check whether the value is `Not Nothing` (VBA does not have a better way of checking whether it is something):

```
If Not i Is Nothing Then
```

---

In general, it is a best practice to always refer to the parent worksheet, when you are referring to `Range()`, `Cells()`, `Rows()`, `Columns()`, because otherwise the range is assigned to the `ActiveSheet` and it may be painful.

However, in this specific case, `j` would be referred to the correct worksheet, because the `i` is assigned to it. Try this small code on an empty Excel file to see - it activates the first worksheet and yet the second is the parent of Range `j`:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Worksheets(1).Activate
    Set ws = Worksheets(2)

    Dim i As Range
    Dim j As Range

    Set i = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Set j = Range(i, i.End(xlDown))
    Debug.Print j.Parent.Name

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for answer and thaks for the tips :)

Comment: @TooMachoBA note that stuff like `Range(i, i.End(xlDown))` refers to the `ActiveSheet` which is not necessarily your `ws` variable. Hence why @ShaiRado put it in the `With` block.

Comment: @Brad - in the context of the question - `Range(i, i.End(xlDown))` cannot refer to the ActiveSheet, because `i` is defined with `ws`.

Comment: If I try this without qualifying `Range` I get `Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed`.

Comment: @Brad - I see. I have added the sample code in the edit.

Comment: @Brad and Vityata Thank you guys :)

Comment: Yeah seems you're right. Except in a few workbooks I have which are not empty it still fails. Not totally clear why though. But qualifying Range allows it to work. I'm more confused than before.

Comment: @Brad -  Sorry for the confusion, in general stick with the `Parent` rule and you will be always on the safe side. The only reason to fail I can think of is because the workbook has 1 worksheet only.

Answer (score 1):

When using the `Find` function, always prepare yourself for a scenario that `Find` failed to find the match, you can do that by having the following line right after your `Find`:

```
If Not i Is Nothing Then
```

***Modified Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Range
Dim j As Range

Set ws = Worksheets("bank")

With ws
    Set i = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Find(What:="MEASURED VALUE", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    ' make sure first find was successful
    If Not i Is Nothing Then
        Set j = .Range(i.Offset(1, 0), i.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown))
    Else
        MsgBox "Error!, couldn't find 'MEASURED VALUE'", vbCritical
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That trick with offset in range brackets is awsome thank you very much. And thx for the `Fide` tip:)